# How to replace occurrence only on the start of the string in Oracle SQL?

Tags: oracle11g, regexp-replace

I have a source column and I want to search for string values starting with 05, 5 971971 and 97105 to be replaced by 9715. As showin in output table.

`SOURCE         OUTPUT
0514377920      971514377920
544233920       971544233920
971971511233920 971511233920
9710511233920   971511233920`

I tried following which works for first case.

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE ('0544377905', '^(\05*)', '9715')FROM dual;
```

But following is not working, for second case:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE ('544377905', '^(\5*)', '9715')FROM dual;
```

Something is wrong with my regular expression. As I am getting: ORA-12727: invalid back reference in regular expression.

Comment: Is your third pattern `971971` supposed to be `9719715`? Can it be generalised - are you really looking to replace everything up to the first 5 in the string, or keep the last 8 characters of any value for instance; or are there other values you don't want to modify?

Comment: If you have any control over it, it would be better to fix the data model. Instead of a single column for the phone number, you should have three: one for country code, one for area (region, province etc.) code and one for the actual number. Unfortunately, quite often people who post here don't have enough power to make such changes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can provide your four patterns using [alternation](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html); that is, in parentheses with a vertical bar between them:

```
with t(source) as (
  select '0514377920' from dual
  union all select '544233920' from dual
  union all select '971971511233920' from dual
  union all select '9710511233920' from dual
)
SELECT source, REGEXP_REPLACE (source, '^(05|5|9719715|97105)', '9715') as output
FROM t;

SOURCE          OUTPUT             
--------------- --------------------
0514377920      971514377920        
544233920       971544233920        
971971511233920 971511233920        
9710511233920   971511233920
```

Depending on your data and any other restrictions you have, you may be able to make it as simple as replacing the first part of any string that has a 5 in it, which works for your small sample:

```
SELECT source, REGEXP_REPLACE (source, '^.[^5]?5', '9715') as output
FROM t;
```

That matches zero or more characters that are not 5, followed by a 5. That may be too simplistic for your real situation though.